# Issue with Ñ character in name (migrated data from MySQL to PostgreSQL)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration

I'm currently running a test migration of data from MySQL to PostgreSQL. I'm using psycopg2 to perform the task.

I was able to migrate the person's information but when I check the data for comparison, some lastnames with Ñ are showing as "?" in psql while some show as Ñ. I checked both server and client encoding in PostgreSQL and they are set to UTF8.

Where should I start troubleshooting this? I'm new to this kind of task.

Comment: have you got the code you're trying to use in your migration? - its most likely being converted out of UTF8 somewhere along the line

Comment: Which encoding is used in MySQL?  Do you have an intermediate state (a file, I guess) where you can check if the exported data looks correct?

Comment: @SteBov, I'm currently looking on the code but one thing I knew is that the DB source that I am playing around in MySQL is a dump file with --compatibility=postgresql of an EXISTING DB in MySQL. This DB was also used to play around with pgloader when testing to move it to postgresql. I compared the data from the original DB and this test DB I am using in MySQL, test DB has "?" marks  as well.

Comment: @dezso I have a csv file of the original DB, and no issue with Enyes

Comment: I'll rewrite the code and access the original DB in mySQL using mysql.connector and psycopg2. What are the things that I need to consider in the code to avoid this?

Comment: Depending on your Python version, the strings might or might not be automatically UTF-8.  Also, you see proper Ñs in the CSV - but are you sure it's UTF-8?  This might depend on the application you are viewing it, too.

Comment: It may also be helpful to know in which environment both DB's and the clients are used.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I am using 2.7 Python. Also I am using Ubuntu as Destkop OS so I'm using LibreOffice to view the csv file. How would I know if Enye is UTF-8 in CSV or not?

Comment: Just read such a value into a python variable and compare it like this: `'Ñ' == u'Ñ'`.  Or just follow the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11607/34908.  To solve your issue, I guess you need to do something like `'Ñ'.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: More Python tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Answer (score 1):

You can start troubleshooting this by looking at the bytes behind the characters, to check if there are invalid UTF-8 contents independently of the display layer.

An UTF-8 string can be converted into its series of bytes in SQL with

```
SELECT convert_to(value, 'UTF-8');
```

You may also split a suspicious string character by character to look at each codepoint individually, with the character, the Unicode codepoint, and the UTF-8 representation

```
SELECT c, to_hex(ascii(c)), convert_to(c, 'UTF-8') FROM
   regexp_split_to_table('El Niño', '') AS c;

 c | to_hex | convert_to 
---+--------+------------
 E | 45     | \x45
 l | 6c     | \x6c
   | 20     | \x20
 N | 4e     | \x4e
 i | 69     | \x69
 ñ | f1     | \xc3b1
 o | 6f     | \x6f
```

I would try this on the  fields where some characters display as `?` and compare with the fields where the characters display correctly. The goal is to identify what's exactly behind the `?`.

Comment: Please use simply `SELECT HEX(c) ...` -- I fear that the other functions called will unexpectedly do some form of charset change, in spite of your `SELECT` correctly showing that `ñ` is hex `f1` in latin1 and `c3b1` in utf8.